Django: how to create a unique instance of one model as a field in another model
I am trying to store an instance of an Item model as a field in my users model using ForeignKey like so:
class UserProfile(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    username = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    items = models.ForeignKey('Item', on_delete=models.CASCADE)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.username
    
class Item(models.Model):
    stats = models.JSONField(null=True)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

However, it currently seems that every new user is sharing the same list of items when I check my Django admin panel (essentially, there currently exists only one Item instance that is shared by every user). Instead, my goal is to have each user have their own list of items, unrelated to other users' list. Is there a way to make each user have a field in their account that is a unique instance of the Items model?

Your ForeignKey is in the wrong direction. A foreign key is a many-to-one relation, therefore your existing model structure implies "many UserProfiles to one Item".
It should be in the Item model:
class Item(models.Model):
    user_profile = models.ForeignKey(
        UserProfile, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name="items"
    )
    ...

A ForeignKey field name should always be singular, and the related_name (i.e. the reverse relation) should be plural, so that both my_user_profile.items and my_item.user_profile make sense.

Thank you, I didn't realize that ForeignKey worked in this way. However, I am realizing in hindsight that this relationship doesn't fully achieve what I am looking for. I now have a ForeignKey in which "many Items are mapped to one UserProfile", however, these items are stored individually in the Items model in my database. This requires me to sort through every single item to find which ones belong to each user. Would there instead be a way to essentially give each user an array of items rather than assigning each individual item to a user?

I don't understand the problem, but database rows are associated using primary keys, and in your example the keys are the id columns. If you know the ids of the Items that a UserProfile owns, you can simply use a for loop to associate those Items with that UserProfile.

You are right, I suppose I'll just use a for loop to group the items and not complicate things further. Thanks!

As a final thought, while this did work in my use-case, my concern is that this solution doesn't seem scalable. If I'm not mistaken, wouldn't associating items to users in this manner cause the response time to fetch any arbitrary user's items increase as a function of number of users? Maybe Django just isn't well-suited for this kind of thing, but I'm left wondering if there's a more scalable solution for this.

Again, it is not clear what your concern is. Fetching any arbitrary User's Items only depend on the number of Items, which is expected. Or are you concerned about fetching each Item, updating the user foreign key, and saving it?

Apologies, to be more specific, in my backend I have a view called get_items which is passed a user as an argument. Here, I retrieve a list of that user's items with the line data = list(Item.objects.filter(user_profile=user_profile).values()). My question is, wouldn't this require the database to "filter" through all items from every user each time a single user's items are requested, therefore increasing RRT for every request as new items accumulate? Perhaps I am misunderstanding how SQL would handle this sort of query? I'm a beginner so I apologize for the confusion.

RTT*, the round trip time of the response.

Because Django will automatically index the FK column (i.e. Item.user_profile) the database engine won't have to perform a full table scan and impact will be minimal. In other words, the engine knows where each Item associated with a given User resides in the table because it keeps a separate hashmap (i.e. index) for this specific purpose. See https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/indexes.html. In general you shouldn't try to micro-optimise your database structure unless you are dealing with millions of records.

Got it. I appreciate your explanation and help with the original issue!
